# how to access Rolename from the group by query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, sql-server

we having two table `SiteRoles` and `SiteRolesModules` . In SiteRolesModules we access `RoleID` in single row based on `ModuleID` .

```
select t1.ModuleID,RoleID=( SELECT RoleID AS [data()]
FROM SiteRoleModules t2  
where t2.ModuleID = t1.ModuleID ORDER BY ModuleID  FOR XML PATH('')) 
from SiteRoleModules t1 GROUP BY ModuleID
```

[image: output]

In above image we got the output. We required Rolename instead of RoleID. RoleID and Rolename is present in `SiteRoles` table

[image: id]

In above image we have `RoleID 1 - administrator, 2 - superAdmin, 3 - admin`

we require output in image 1 Instead of RoleID 1 2 3 we need output as administrator superAdmin admin

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MEDEIL_SiteRoleModules_SelectOne] 
@ModuleID int
AS
SELECT
   SRM.RoleID,
   SR.RoleName
FROM
   [dbo].[SiteRoleModules]  SRM 
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[SiteRoles] SR 
   ON SR.RoleID = SRM.RoleID
WHERE ModuleID = 1
```

Comment: Remove the images and add sample table data and expected output in text fomat

Comment: @Wanderer check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you can use `join` to perform it;

```
select t1.ModuleID,RoleName=(  SELECT s1.RoleName AS [data()]

           FROM SiteRoleModules t2 inner join SiteRoles s1 ON t2.RoleID = s1.RoleID 
           where t2.ModuleID = t1.ModuleID group by s1.RoleName FOR XML PATH('')) from SiteRoleModules t1 GROUP BY ModuleID
```

Comment: if i will pass the ModuleID value 1 then corresponding RoleName value should display but here i pass  value 1 in ModuleID it display all the ModuleID. how to change my query.

Comment: No, you shouldn't pass constant value as ModuleId in subquery. Put your where clause main query.

Comment: see above image i need to display only one value

Comment: Your question changed... Put the group by after where clause in your query. "group by SRM.RoleId, SR.RoleName "

Comment: Yes sir i need display i will pass the ModuleID value 1 then corresponding RoleName value should display how to change in your query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160689/discussion-between-rainman-and-ivin-raj).

Comment: when i command RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RoleID"]), then only working i need to get RoleID Also please help me